# Trying to bake an iridescent texture

Tags: texture-baking

So I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMiXPjwSkEo) tutorial on youtube to get an iridescent kind of material, and I added an image texture node to bake it but when I do, it only bakes the base purple color, not the others. I'm not really all that well versed in using nodes, I just tend to follow the tutorial for whatever material I need on youtube.

I've read [here](https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/419945-iridescent-texture/) that you can do this in Maya, but I don't have access to that program. 
[image: this is what I'm looking at in blender]

any help would be super appreciated, thank you in advance! :D

Comment: What do you expect from baking? Your colors change depending of the viewing angle. If you bake colors from the current camera angle, they would be wrong from qny other angle, making the baking as useful as a still rendering.

Comment: @Leander What I'm trying to do is bake what I see in the view port from this angle. I know that once I bake the texture the colors won't change when I change the angle and that's fine. I'm just trying to get the multiple colors I see in front view to bake onto the texture, but I can't figure out how to do that. It only bakes the purple color

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace the *Layer Weight* node with a *Normal Map* node.

I played around with the normal color and strength to get a result I liked.
(The image texture I'm using is just an image of a gradient)

[image]

Comment: I think this could work as an approach. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more or show an example of how this solution would look like when baked?